# How to "auto" pageStartIndex so that when clicking on a link to go to another table pagination automatically starts at desired row table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out a way to click a link inside a table and have it take me to another table on a different page, but pagination also defaults to 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using pagination={paginationFactory} to use the navigating logic in my <BootstrapTable